# How to fix "PHP Warning: ftp_login(): Login authentication failed"

Tags: php, cpanel, centos7

I use centos 7 with cPanel.

I have installed Open Game Panel.

So the panel is installed `/home/user/public_html/panel`. With subdomain `panel.ubc-cs.net`.

After that i create new Counter Strike server and tried to login from ftp and i see this error:

> *AN ERROR HAS OCCURED
>   Unable to login to FTP server 144.91.80.0 with username 80.
>   Are you sure your username and password are correct? Please contact your ISP helpdesk or system administrator for help.*.

After that i check the error logs on `/home/user/logs/panel_ubc-cs_net.php.error.log` and now here i see this error:

> *[12-Oct-2019 14:47:59 Europe/Paris] PHP Warning:  ftp_login(): Login authentication failed in /home/ubc/public_html/panel/modules/ftp/includes/filesystem.inc.php on line 61*

Comment: _with username 80_ Is your username really `80`

Comment: Username 80 is username of game server. When i create new server then ogp_agent give username of the next server 80, 81, 82... Also when i go to change username i cant change. When i hade OGP installed on Ubuntu o didnt have this problem with ftp. Only here on Centos.